# Compute binomials choose(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!) using memoization

Tags: java, algorithm

Binomial function choose(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)!)
How to write a program to compute 10^8 = 100 million random binomials with N randomly selected from 1 to 52, and R randomly selected 0 to n.

Need to compute the binomial in O(1) time by using  memo-ization or something similar.

My code is like that. I know in every recursion, one element may calculate twice, I don't know how to make it more efficient by using memoization.

```
public static int choose(int n, int k){
    if(k == 0) return 1;

    return (n * choose(n - 1, k - 1)) / k;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a homework question. Please make an attempt to write code to complete the requirement. Then ask if you have specific issues.

Comment: With N and R that low, you probably want to use the Pascal Triangle formula, not the one you have in the question text. Still, the value C(50, 25) does not fit into an `int`, so a `long` would be needed.

Comment: 1430 binomials (unless I've made a mistake with my maths, but it should at least be close) and 100mio binomials? Just build a table. Or is this about the computation of the binomials themselves? And use `long` to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you may get too large numbers for the integer data type... [Proof](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max(Binom%5B52,%20x%5D),%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%2052).

The idea is that you go step by step... multiplying by subsequent numbers from dividend and dividing by subsequent numbers from divisor.

```
public class Binom {

    private long[][] mapped;

    public Binom(){
        mapped = new long[52][52];
    }

    public long binom(int n, int r) {
        if (r == 0)
            return 1;
        if (r == 1)
            return n;

        if(r > n-r)
            r = n-r;
        long toReturn = 1;
        for (int i = 1, m = n; i <= r; i++, m--){
            toReturn = toReturn*m/i;
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public long[][] getMapped() {
        return mapped;
    }
}
```

My benchmark:

```
public class Benchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Random random = new Random();
        int count = 1;
        Binom binom = new Binom();
        long[][] mapped = binom.getMapped();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100_000_000; i++) {
            int n = 1 + random.nextInt(52);
            int r = 1 + random.nextInt(n);
            long result = mapped[n-1][r-1];
            if (result != 0) {
                System.out.println(count++ + ". Binomial for n: " + n + " and r: " + r + " equals " + result + ".");
            } else {
                result = binom.binom(n, r);
                mapped[n-1][r-1] = result;
                System.out.println(count++ + ". Binomial for n: " + n + " and r: " + r + " equals " + result + ".");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The whole lasted " + ((System.nanoTime() - start)/1_000_000_000) + " seconds.");
    }
}
```

End of output:

```
99999995. Binomial for n: 3 and r: 3 equals 1.
99999996. Binomial for n: 19 and r: 17 equals 171.
99999997. Binomial for n: 26 and r: 20 equals 230230.
99999998. Binomial for n: 32 and r: 13 equals 347373600.
99999999. Binomial for n: 20 and r: 14 equals 38760.
100000000. Binomial for n: 3 and r: 3 equals 1.
The whole lasted 342 seconds.
```

Without printing it would be faster... You only need to compute binomial coefficient for those `1378=(52*52/2)` pairs.

Comment: @ruakh, not microscale but [that](https://dzone.com/articles/abstraction-slows-you-down).

Comment: @ruakh, corrected. Switched from `HashMap` to `long[][]`. `int[][]` would not be enough.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you could use memoization in this case efficiently would be to put your results in a `static Map<myObject, int>`, where `myObject` is an object with n and k values as the key and int is the result. So every time you would have to store or find the results before calculating or/and returning your answers.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful (because it's not clear what is `myObject`. Also, you can't use primitive type `int` in Java now. Also, using `Map` is really, really inefficient way to solve problem.

Comment: Or just use an array, since the total number of binomials that are computed is pretty low to speedup lookup. `Map` tends to slow things down quite a bit.

Comment: And it most certainly is not the only way.